# Rename [attack-the-light] → [steven-universe-attack-the-light]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I would like to propose renaming the tag for [*Steven Universe: Attack the Light!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Universe:_Attack_the_Light!)

- [attack-the-light](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack-the-light) → [steven-universe-attack-the-light](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steven-universe-attack-the-light) (32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag Rename Done:

- [attack-the-light](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack-the-light) → [steven-universe-attack-the-light](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steven-universe-attack-the-light)